# Convert index to pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a dataset that have two index and one column, like this:

```
                         value
cod      Date               
A        2011-01-01  5.540642
         2011-02-01  5.556837
         2011-03-01  5.565547
         2011-04-01  5.557245
         2011-05-01  5.604736
         2011-06-01  5.570242
         2011-07-01  5.578222
         2011-08-01  5.826457
         2011-09-01  6.391667
         2011-10-01  6.880779
         2011-11-01  5.610012
         2011-12-01  5.572432
```

I want convert index in pandas column. When I use the follow code: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` it do what i want. But if I try to put it in another object, to create a new dataset: `df1 = df.reset_index(inplace=True)`, the function give me an empty object, precisally NoneType object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `inplace=True` in [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `inplace=False` what is default parameter, so should be omitted.

> **inplace** : boolean, default False
>
> Modify the DataFrame in place (do not create a new object)

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
```